# Simple mind-blowing thing; CSS selectors vs jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pseudo-class

CSS selector **:not()** is not working and jQuery **:not** does.
Consider this structure:

```
<div class="main">
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
<div>
    <div class="doc-view">
        <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this simple CSS:

```
li:not(.doc-view li) {
    color:green;
}
```

And a little of jQuery here:

```
$('li:not(.doc-view li)').css('color','red');
```

As you can see, selectors are the same. But if you play with jsFiddle, you will see, that are not the same. jQuery selector targets elements, CSS does not.

http://jsfiddle.net/LL429/3/

EDIT:

The question is:

How to target all <li>s on the page, except those which are in .doc-view container?

Comment: Thank you for posting a decent question.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Quentin, updated. Could you answer now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because they mean different things. Let's start with the CSS.

```
li:not(.doc-view li)
```

This means select all list items, but not those that have descendants that have the class doc-view with a list item descendant. Your code has none of those, plus only [simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) are allow to be used with `:not()`, so the selector is invalid anyway.

Now for the jQuery.

```
$('li:not(.doc-view li)')
```

This says select all list items, but do not include in that collection any elements with the class doc-view with a list item descendant. This works because it first select all list items, and then removes the matching group of elements that fit the `:not(.doc-view li)` selector.

Comment: The CSS does not mean that. The CSS is invalid. You may only use a simple selector in `:not()`. http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation

Comment: @Quentin - Ah true, although even with a simple selector here he's still comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: @j08691 Great answer, thanks!
And do you know, how to answer my question with pure CSS?

Comment: A simple solution would be to target all the lis with one style, then target those in the doc-view div with a separate style. You won't be able to target them differently with a single rule in pure CSS.

Comment: @j08691 Imagine I have no access to .doc-view html and css. If so, should I use jQuery for targeting <li>s outside .doc-view?

Comment: That sounds like the easiest thing to do.

Comment: @antonama - [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24916219/682480) shows a pure CSS solution (not that I'm trying to steal the checkmark, just showing how to do it).

Comment: @Code Maverick, yes, I see. But, unfortunately, I have no access to .doc-view CSS, and it might stay unchangeable.

Comment: @antonama - If you don't have access to change the HTML or CSS, how would you implement any of the answers?

Comment: @antonama - Ok, so as you know, if your CSS is after that of the .doc-view CSS, it will overwrite the previous styles.

Answer (score 2):

CSS selectors != jQuery selectors.

[jQuery uses Sizzle CSS selector engine](http://sizzlejs.com/).

Try:

```
ul > li {
    color:green;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JFCwd/)**

Comment: Or just `.main >ul > li`  ?

Comment: `.doc-view` is on the `div` not the `li` so it will always be true.

Comment: I think I know something about CSS selectors.
The goal is not to target specific li elements, the goal is to show, how different equal selectors work in jQuery and CSS.
But thanks for tht answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since `.doc-view` is on the `div`, you need to use the negation on the `div` and then access the `li`.

So the pure CSS solution is:

```css
ul > li {
   color: red;
}

div:not(.doc-view) > ul > li {
   color:green;
}
```

***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vpX9w/)***